# getPropertyValue('font-size') returns different value for firefox and chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, firefox, font-size

I am using the following code which I adapted from here: [How To Get Font Size in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15195209/how-to-get-font-size-in-html)

the code is:

```
function checkminfont() {
var el = document.getElementById('fontcheck');
var style = window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
var fontSize = parseFloat(style);
alert(fontSize);
}
```

the element with Id "fontcheck" is a div with font size set to 11.  I am trying to find a reliable way to find out if a user's minimum font size is set above 11. In Chrome this function works perfectly - when the minimum font size is above 11, the alert will give the value of the minimum font size. In Firefox, the alert says 11 no matter what the minimum font size is set to. Why is that? is there a way to reliably test for minimum font size in firefox? Ultimately, I am trying to enlarge certain elements so they will be proportional if the user increases their font size.

Comment: "*I am trying to enlarge certain elements so they will be proportional if the user increases their font size.*". Then just use `em` units. There is no need of JS.

Comment: I may be able to accomplish some of what I'd like to do with em - but I would like to have more flexibility - for example I may want to load larger images instead of just blowing them up, etc. Ultimately, I would like this to work just so I can test different strategies and see which looks and functions the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works on firefox as well:

```
function checkminfont() {
var m = '<div id="min-font-size-tester"';
m += ' style="font-size: 2px; line-height: 1;';
m += ' display: none;">M</div>';
$('body').append(m);
minsize = $('#min-font-size-tester').height();
alert(minsize);
}
```

my thanks to Bobby Jack: http://www.fiveminuteargument.com/minimum-font-scaler