# Select DOM nodes by their font-size in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a html content with different styles. I need to find the node using `font-size`. For example, find nodes which had `font-size: 10pt`.

```css
.classname1 {
  color: red;
  font-size: 10pt;
}

.classname2 {
  color: red;
  font-size: 11pt;
}

.classname3 {
  color: red;
  font-size: 12pt;
}

.classname4 {
  color: green;
  font-size: 10pt;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello <span class="classname1">world!</span></p>
<p>Hello <span class="classname2">Paul</span></p>
<p>Hello <span class="classname3">raj</span></p>
<p>Hello <span class="classname4">moon</span></p>
```

In this code I need to find a node with style `font-size: 10pt`.

Comment: You really need to find all DOM elements with that font-size or all CSS classes using that font-size?

Comment: @Sirko i need all DOM element with that font-size

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select all elements that have a specific CSS, using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220834/select-all-elements-that-have-a-specific-css-using-jquery)

Comment: Should this be restrictive to other units ? I mean, do you also want to find elements that have the font-size set to e.g `13.3333px` ?

Comment: @Kaiido i just asked the example with `font-size:10pt`. i also want to find elements with different font-size

Comment: Alright, then you already have got two correct answers (since 72 / 96 === .75)

Comment: yes that's useful for me

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `font-size` speicifically in `points (e.g. 10pt)`, you can convert the `font-size` returned in `px` using `fontSize * 72 / 96` to `pt` and then compare it with `10` or whichever font-size you have.

Used `Math.round` for handling precision in conversion.

Find working snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var x = $('*').filter(function() {
    return Math.round(parseFloat($(this).css("font-size")) * 72 / 96) === 10
  });
  console.log(x.length)
});
```

```css
.classname1 {
  color: red;
  font-size: 10pt;
}

.classname2 {
  color: red;
  font-size: 11pt;
}

.classname3 {
  color: red;
  font-size: 12pt;
}

.classname4 {
  color: green;
  font-size: 10pt;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <p>Hello <span class="classname1">world!</span></p>
  <p>Hello <span class="classname2">Paul</span></p>
  <p>Hello <span class="classname3">raj</span></p>
  <p>Hello <span class="classname4">moon</span></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not very `select` by, but maybe will fits your needs:

```js
$('p > span').each(function() {
  var pt = Math.round(parseFloat($(this).css('font-size')) * 0.75);
  if(pt == 10) {
    $(this).css('color', 'pink');
  }
});
```

```css
  .classname1 {
    color: red;
    font-size: 10pt;
  }

  .classname2 {
    color: red;
    font-size: 11pt;
  }

  .classname3 {
    color: red;
    font-size: 12pt;
  }

  .classname4 {
    color: green;
    font-size: 10pt;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Hello <span class="classname1">world!</span></p>
<p>Hello <span class="classname2">Paul</span></p>
<p>Hello <span class="classname3">raj</span></p>
<p>Hello <span class="classname4">moon</span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just loop through all elements

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
var sel = [];
for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
     if (all[i].style.fontSize == '10pt') {
          sel.push(all[i]);
     }
}
```

Comment: `style.fontSize == '10pt'`won't work if the font was set by CSS, and not JS. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15195209/how-to-get-font-size-in-html

Comment: @flen right, though we could convert the returned size to `pt` and then compare? :-) not so amazing but still works! (as I added in answer)

Comment: @tanmay, your answer, (which has the same code as the one by Sojtin btw) uses $el.css, which returns the computed style  and, hence, which is not concerned by this `element.style.prop !== getCOmputedStyle(elem).prop` problem

Comment: @tanmay exactly like Kaiido said, the problem with monkeyinsght's answer is that `all[i].style.fontSize` will return an empty string if it was set by CSS. Try monkeyinsight's code on this StackOverflow page with '15px' instead of '10pt'. You'll see it won't return anything at all (I just tried it)

Comment: @flen yes, thanks for the explanation.. got the difference!

Comment: this is not working for external css and internal css.it's working only for inline css

Answer (score 0):

**JS Vanilla, calculate Computed styles, with precision option**

Basically i took bits of everyones answers, combined them, added extra options, removed jQuery dependency.

```js
/*Settings*/
var decimalPrecision = 0; //with precision 3 - Test6 will not get selected
var targetSize = 10; //pt
var targetElems = document.querySelectorAll(".check");//css selector, IE8+

for (var i = 0, max = targetElems.length; i < max; i++) {
  var fontSize = window.getComputedStyle(targetElems[i], null)['font-size'];//IE9+
  fontSize = (parseFloat(fontSize.substr(0, fontSize.length - 2)) * 72 / 96).toFixed(decimalPrecision);
  if (fontSize == targetSize)targetElems[i].classList.add("targetSize");
}
```

```css
.targetSize {
  color: red;
}

.a1 {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.a2 {
  font-size: 10pt;
}

.a3 {
  font-size: 11pt;
}

.a4 {
  font-size: .8333rem;
}

.a5 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.a6 {
  font-size: 13.3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a1 check">Test1</div>
<div class="a2 check">Test2</div>
<div class="a3 check">Test3</div>
<div class="a4 check">Test4</div>
<div class="a5 check">Test5</div>
<div class="a6 check">Test6</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var tag=document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for(var i=0;i<tag.length;i++)
{ 
if(parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(tag[i].childNodes[1], null).getPropertyValue('font-size'))=='13.3333')
{
console.log(tag[i].childNodes[1])
}};

Use this JS code and you will get what you want..
You have to compare the font as in a little difference between pixel and pt..
```

:)

Comment: if we get the property value then how can i get the value from external css