# Remove whitespace from first and last character on multiple headline sizes

Tags: javascript, css, typography

I try to get div fitting headlines, so far so good. But know I got problems with the default whitespace of the characters (
particularly with the even ones like I,L,P,H). I've tried to manage it with the letter spacing (doesn't work), than I've tried to solve it with text justification (didn't get a solution as well)... Does anybody know a way to handle it? Thanks

```js
function scaleHeader() {
  var vw = ($(window).width())* 0.01;
  console.log(vw)
  var scalable = document.querySelectorAll('h1');
  for (var i = 0; i < scalable.length; i++) {
    var scalableContainer = scalable[i].parentNode;
    scalable[i].style.transform = 'scale(1)';
    var scalableContainerWidth = scalableContainer.offsetWidth; 
    
    var scalableWidth = scalable[i].offsetWidth;
    scalable[i].style.transform = 'scale(' + scalableContainerWidth / scalableWidth + ')';
    
    
    var firstletter = $(scalable[i]).text().slice(0,1);
    var lastletter = $(scalable[i]).text().slice(-1);
    
    if((firstletter.match(/(B|D|E|F|H|I|K|L|M|N|P|R|U|b|i|k|l|m|n|p|r)/)) && (lastletter.match(/(I|U|i|j|l|q|u)/))){
      //Here I don't know what to do!
    }
    
    if ($(scalableContainer).text().match(/(g|y|j|q|p)/)){
      scalableContainer.style.height = scalable[i].getBoundingClientRect().height * 1.05 + 'px' ;
    } else { 
      scalableContainer.style.height = scalable[i].getBoundingClientRect().height * 0.85 + 'px' ;
    }
  }  
}

scaleHeader();
window.addEventListener('resize', scaleHeader);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.third {
  display:inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: red;
  
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 33vw;
  heigth: auto;
}

.half {
  display:inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: red;
  
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 49.5vw;
  heigth: auto;
} 

.scale--js {
  display: inline-block;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: translate3d( 0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="third"> 
      <h1 class="scale--js">Mai</h1>  
</div>

<div class="third"> 
      <h1 class="scale--js">Juni</h1>   
</div>

<div class="third"> 
      <h1 class="scale--js">Heute</h1>  
</div>  

<div class="half">
    <h1 class="scale--js">A'm full widthq</h1>
</div> 

<div class="third"> 
      <h1 class="scale--js">ij</h1>   
</div>

<div class="half"> 
      <h1 class="scale--js">Aktuell</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: [Maybe try getting the font size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15195209/how-to-get-font-size-in-html) and treating the width differently based on what the first and last letter are in combination with the font size? This is an interesting one...

Comment: The problem is that all of them have the same font size, cause I'm try to fit the div with scaling the text to the right width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using a modifiction of bigtext.js. In case somebody else needs it.

```js
/*! BigText - v1.0.1 - 2017-06-01
 * https://github.com/zachleat/bigtext
 * Copyright (c) 2017 Zach Leatherman (@zachleat)
 * MIT License */

(function(window, $) {
  "use strict";

  var counter = 0,
    $headCache = $('head'),
    oldBigText = window.BigText,
    oldjQueryMethod = $.fn.bigtext,
    BigText = {
      DEBUG_MODE: false,
      DEFAULT_MIN_FONT_SIZE_PX: null,
      DEFAULT_MAX_FONT_SIZE_PX: 100000000,
      GLOBAL_STYLE_ID: 'bigtext-style',
      STYLE_ID: 'bigtext-id',
      LINE_CLASS_PREFIX: 'bigtext-line',
      EXEMPT_CLASS: 'bigtext-exempt',
      noConflict: function(restore)
      {
        if(restore) {
          $.fn.bigtext = oldjQueryMethod;
          window.BigText = oldBigText;
        }
        return BigText;
      },
      supports: {
        wholeNumberFontSizeOnly: (function() {
          if( !( 'getComputedStyle' in window ) ) {
            return true;
          }
          var test = $('<div/>').css({
              position: 'absolute',
              'font-size': '14.1px',
            }).insertBefore( $('script').eq(0) ),
            computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle( test[0], null );

          var ret = computedStyle && computedStyle.getPropertyValue( 'font-size' ) === '14px';
          test.remove();
          return ret;
        })()
      },
      init: function() {
        if(!$('#'+BigText.GLOBAL_STYLE_ID).length) {
          $headCache.append(BigText.generateStyleTag(BigText.GLOBAL_STYLE_ID, ['.bigtext * { white-space: nowrap; } .bigtext > * { display: block; }',
                                          '.bigtext .' + BigText.EXEMPT_CLASS + ', .bigtext .' + BigText.EXEMPT_CLASS + ' * { white-space: normal; }']));
        }
      },
      bindResize: function(eventName, resizeFunction) {
        var timeoutId;
        $(window).unbind(eventName).bind(eventName, function() {
          if( timeoutId ) {
            clearTimeout( timeoutId );
          }
          timeoutId = setTimeout( resizeFunction, 100 );
        });
      },
      getStyleId: function(id)
      {
        return BigText.STYLE_ID + '-' + id;
      },
      generateStyleTag: function(id, css)
      {
        return $('<style>' + css.join('\n') + '</style>').attr('id', id);
      },
      clearCss: function(id)
      {
        var styleId = BigText.getStyleId(id);
        $('#' + styleId).remove();
      },
      generateCss: function(id, linesFontSizes, lineWordSpacings, minFontSizes)
      {
        var css = [];

        BigText.clearCss(id);

        for(var j=0, k=linesFontSizes.length; j<k; j++) {
          css.push('#' + id + ' .' + BigText.LINE_CLASS_PREFIX + j + ' {' +
            (minFontSizes[j] ? ' white-space: normal;' : '') +
            (linesFontSizes[j] ? ' font-size: ' + linesFontSizes[j] + 'px;' : '') +
            (lineWordSpacings[j] ? ' word-spacing: ' + lineWordSpacings[j] + 'px;' : '') +
            '}');
        }

        return BigText.generateStyleTag(BigText.getStyleId(id), css);
      },
      jQueryMethod: function(options)
      {
        BigText.init();

        options = $.extend({
          minfontsize: BigText.DEFAULT_MIN_FONT_SIZE_PX,
          maxfontsize: BigText.DEFAULT_MAX_FONT_SIZE_PX,
          childSelector: '',
          resize: true
        }, options || {});

        this.each(function()
        {
          var $t = $(this).addClass('bigtext'),
            maxWidth = $t.width(),
            id = $t.attr('id'),
            $children = options.childSelector ? $t.find( options.childSelector ) : $t.children();

          if(!id) {
            id = 'bigtext-id' + (counter++);
            $t.attr('id', id);
          }

          if(options.resize) {
            BigText.bindResize('resize.bigtext-event-' + id, function()
            {
              // TODO only call this if the width has changed.
              BigText.jQueryMethod.call($('#' + id), options);
            });
          }

          BigText.clearCss(id);

          $children.addClass(function(lineNumber, className)
          {
            // remove existing line classes.
            return [className.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + BigText.LINE_CLASS_PREFIX + '\\d+\\b'), ''),
                BigText.LINE_CLASS_PREFIX + lineNumber].join(' ');
          });

          var sizes = BigText.calculateSizes($t, $children, maxWidth, options.maxfontsize, options.minfontsize);
          $headCache.append(BigText.generateCss(id, sizes.fontSizes, sizes.wordSpacings, sizes.minFontSizes));

        });

        return this.trigger('bigtext:complete');
      },
      testLineDimensions: function($line, maxWidth, property, size, interval, units, previousWidth)
      {
        var width;
        previousWidth = typeof previousWidth === 'number' ? previousWidth : 0;
        $line.css(property, size + units);

        width = $line.width();

        if(width >= maxWidth) {
    // console.log(width, ' previous: ' + previousWidth, property + ' at ' + interval, 'prior: ' + (parseFloat(size) - interval), 'new:' + parseFloat(size));
          $line.css(property, '');

          if(width === maxWidth) {
            return {
              match: 'exact',
              size: parseFloat((parseFloat(size) - 0.1).toFixed(3))
            };
          }

          // Since this is an estimate, we calculate how far over the width we went with the new value.
          // If this is word-spacing (our last resort guess) and the over is less than the under, we keep the higher value.
          // Otherwise, we revert to the underestimate.
          var under = maxWidth - previousWidth,
            over = width - maxWidth;

          return {
            match: 'estimate',
            size: parseFloat((parseFloat(size) - (property === 'word-spacing' && previousWidth && ( over < under ) ? 0 : interval)).toFixed(3))
          };
        }

        return width;
      },
      calculateSizes: function($t, $children, maxWidth, maxFontSize, minFontSize)
      {
        var $c = $t.clone(true)
          .addClass('bigtext-cloned')
          .css({
            fontFamily: $t.css('font-family'),
            textTransform: $t.css('text-transform'),
            wordSpacing: $t.css('word-spacing'),
            letterSpacing: $t.css('letter-spacing'),
            position: 'absolute',
            left: BigText.DEBUG_MODE ? 0 : -9999,
            top: BigText.DEBUG_MODE ? 0 : -9999
          })
          .appendTo(document.body);

        // font-size isn't the only thing we can modify, we can also mess with:
        // word-spacing and letter-spacing. WebKit does not respect subpixel
        // letter-spacing, word-spacing, or font-size.
        // TODO try -webkit-transform: scale() as a workaround.
        var fontSizes = [],
          wordSpacings = [],
          minFontSizes = [],
          ratios = [];

        $children.css('float', 'left').each(function() {
          var $line = $(this),
            // TODO replace 8, 4 with a proportional size to the calculated font-size.
            intervals = BigText.supports.wholeNumberFontSizeOnly ? [8, 4, 1] : [8, 4, 1, 0.1],
            lineMax,
            newFontSize;

          if($line.hasClass(BigText.EXEMPT_CLASS)) {
            fontSizes.push(null);
            ratios.push(null);
            minFontSizes.push(false);
            return;
          }

          // TODO we can cache this ratio?
          var autoGuessSubtraction = 32, // font size in px
            currentFontSize = parseFloat($line.css('font-size')),
            ratio = ( $line.width() / currentFontSize ).toFixed(6);

          newFontSize = parseInt( maxWidth / ratio, 10 ) - autoGuessSubtraction;

          outer: for(var m=0, n=intervals.length; m<n; m++) {
            inner: for(var j=1, k=10; j<=k; j++) {
              if(newFontSize + j*intervals[m] > maxFontSize) {
                newFontSize = maxFontSize;
                break outer;
              }

              lineMax = BigText.testLineDimensions($line, maxWidth, 'font-size', newFontSize + j*intervals[m], intervals[m], 'px', lineMax);
              if(typeof lineMax !== 'number') {
                newFontSize = lineMax.size;

                if(lineMax.match === 'exact') {
                  break outer;
                }
                break inner;
              }
            }
          }

          ratios.push(maxWidth / newFontSize);

          if(newFontSize > maxFontSize) {
            fontSizes.push(maxFontSize);
            minFontSizes.push(false);
          } else if(!!minFontSize && newFontSize < minFontSize) {
            fontSizes.push(minFontSize);
            minFontSizes.push(true);
          } else {
            fontSizes.push(newFontSize);
            minFontSizes.push(false);
          }
        }).each(function(lineNumber) {
          var $line = $(this),
            wordSpacing = 0,
            interval = 1,
            maxWordSpacing;

          if($line.hasClass(BigText.EXEMPT_CLASS)) {
            wordSpacings.push(null);
            return;
          }

          // must re-use font-size, even though it was removed above.
          $line.css('font-size', fontSizes[lineNumber] + 'px');

          for(var m=1, n=3; m<n; m+=interval) {
            maxWordSpacing = BigText.testLineDimensions($line, maxWidth, 'word-spacing', m, interval, 'px', maxWordSpacing);
            if(typeof maxWordSpacing !== 'number') {
              wordSpacing = maxWordSpacing.size;
              break;
            }
          }

          $line.css('font-size', '');
          wordSpacings.push(wordSpacing);
        }).removeAttr('style');

        if( !BigText.DEBUG_MODE ) {
          $c.remove();
        } else {
          $c.css({
            'background-color': 'rgba(255,255,255,.4)'
          });
        }

        return {
          fontSizes: fontSizes,
          wordSpacings: wordSpacings,
          ratios: ratios,
          minFontSizes: minFontSizes
        };
      }
    };

  $.fn.bigtext = BigText.jQueryMethod;
  window.BigText = BigText;

})(this, jQuery);



//Here is my modification



$(document).ready(function(){

  $('h1').bigtext({
    childSelector: '> p',
  });


  $('p').each(function() {
    var firstletter = $(this).text().slice(0,1);
    var lastletter = $(this).text().slice(-1);
    var fontSize = $(this).css('fontSize');
    var fontSizeRaw = parseInt(fontSize, 10);

    if((firstletter.match(/(B|D|E|F|H|I|K|L|M|N|P|R|U|b|i|k|l|m|n|p|r)/)) && (lastletter.match(/(I|U|i|j|l|q|u)/))){
      var mrg= - fontSizeRaw / 36;


      $(this).html(function (i, html) {
        var chars = $.trim(html).split("");
        return '<span>' + chars.join('</span><span>') + '</span>';
      });

      $(this).children(":first").css('marginLeft', mrg + 'px');
      $(this).children(":last").css('marginRight', mrg + 'px');
       
    } else if (firstletter.match(/(B|D|E|F|H|I|K|L|M|N|P|R|U|b|i|k|l|m|n|p|r)/)){
      var mrg= - fontSizeRaw / 36;

      $(this).html(function (i, html) {
        var chars = $.trim(html).split("");
        return html.replace(/\S/g, '<span>$&</span>');
      });

      $(this).children(":first").css('marginLeft', mrg + 'px');
       
    } else if (lastletter.match(/(I|U|i|j|l|q|u)/)){
      var mrg= - fontSizeRaw / 36;

      $(this).html(function (i, html) {
        var chars = $.trim(html).split("");
        return html.replace(/\S/g, '<span>$&</span>');
      });

      $(this).children(":last").css('marginRight', mrg + 'px');
       
    } else {

      $(this).html(function (i, html) {
        var chars = $.trim(html).split("");
        return html.replace(/\S/g, '<span>$&</span>');
      });

    }

    if ($(this).text().match(/(g|y|j|q|p)/)){
      $(this).children().css('marginTop', '-' + fontSizeRaw * 0.1 + 'px' );
      $(this).css('height', fontSizeRaw * 0.80 + 'px' );
    } else {
      $(this).children().css('marginTop', '-' + fontSizeRaw * 0.1 + 'px' );
      $(this).css('height', fontSizeRaw * 0.63 + 'px' );
    }

  });
});
```

```css
*{
  font-family: "FoundersGroteskXCond-Med", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1{ 
 font-weight: normal;
 margin: 0 !important
}

.quater{
  height: auto;
  width: 32.33333vw;
  background-color: red;
}

.half{
  width: 65.666vw;
  background-color: red;
}

.grid > div{
  display: inline-block;
 margin: 0.5vw;
}


.ll{
  zoom: 103%;
}

p {
 padding-top: 0;
    display: flex !important;
    justify-content: space-between;
    /*background-color: blue;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid">

  <div class="quater">
    <h1>
      <p>Wolfgang Mattheuer</p>
    </h1>
  </div> 

  <div class="quater">
    <h1>
      <p>Palawi</p>
    </h1>
  </div> 

  <div class="quater">
    <h1>
      <p>Rog</p>
    </h1>
  </div> 

  <div class="quater">
    <h1>
      <p>News</p>
    </h1>
  </div>

    <div class="half">
    <h1>
      <p>Tanja Zimmermann</p>
    </h1>
  </div> 

  <div class="quater">
    <h1>
      <p>Heute</p>
    </h1>
  </div>

  <div class="quater">
    <h1>
      <p>News</p>
    </h1>
  </div>

  <div class="quater">
    <h1>
      <p>Heute</p>
    </h1>
  </div>
  
  <div class="half">
    <h1>
      <p>Juli</p>
    </h1>
  </div>
  
  <div class="quater">
    <h1>
      <p>Aktuell</p>
    </h1>
  </div>

  <div class="quater">
    <h1>
      <p>lll</p>
    </h1>
  </div>
  
 </body>
```