# Increment a font size onclick event

Tags: javascript

In the new JS, I would like to understand how to make a simple increase of a font size of a text. 
My goal is to onclick the text and sees increasing.

I tried something like that without success:

```
function increaseFontSize(objId) {
    obj = document.getElementById(objId);
    //get current font size of obj
    currentSize = parseFloat(obj.style.fontSize); //parseFloat gives you just the numerical value, i.e. strips the 'em' bit away
    obj.style.fontSize = (currentSize + .1) + "em";
}
```

I would like to see a demo with the new JS like the querySelector or else to solve this simple issue to allow me to learn the correct way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Get Font Size in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15195209/how-to-get-font-size-in-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do something like the following.

```js
const p = document.querySelector('p');
p.addEventListener("click", updateFontSize);

function updateFontSize() {
  const style = window.getComputedStyle(p, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
  const fontSize = parseFloat(style);
  p.style.fontSize = (fontSize + 10) + 'px';
}
```

```html
<p>Test</p>
```

Comment: Nice example but trying this on JSfiddles is giving me this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: updateFontSize is not defined
    at HTMLParagraphElement.onclick` ?

Comment: ah yeah, that is because you need to update the js load type on js fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/xv0u4z3p/ If you look here you will see it works. Play around with the load type in the dropdown in the js section.

Answer (score 2):

Get the `font-size` of your element (with [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) function), increase it, then assign it to the element again:

```js
document.getElementById('myText').addEventListener("click", function () {
  let fontSize = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(this, null).getPropertyValue('font-size'));
  fontSize++;
  this.style.fontSize = fontSize + 'px';
});
```

```html
<div id="myText">My text</div>
```

Comment: `getComputedStyle()` doesn't need `getPropertyValue()` Both are methods by the way and should be written with `()` after them. Also, when there is no psudeo-class, the second argument can be omitted instead of passing `null`.

Answer (score 2):

The `style` property of an element only returns style information that has been set on the `style` attribute in the HTML. If the `style` has been set via a `class` or through JavaScript, you will get `undefined`. Instead, use [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStylev), which will return the current style information, regardless of how it was set.

Also, you probably don't want to increase the font size with:

```
currentSize + .1 + "em"
```

Since [`em` is a unit that is relative to the size of the parent element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units). If say, an element has parent element with a font size of `16px` (the default size of normal text in most browsers) and you strip off the `px` and then add `.1em` to it, you'll have a new size of `16.1em`, which means 16.1 times the parent element size (16 x 16.1 = 257.6px). If you really want to use `em`, you should just make it `1.1` for a slight size increase, otherwise stick with `px` and just bump it up by `1` (shown below).

```js
// Instead of the function only being able to work when an element
// id is passed to it, have the function work as long as an element
// reference itself is passed to it. This is more flexible, since
// not all elements will have an id.
function increaseFontSize(element) {
  console.clear();
  currentSize = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(element).fontSize); 
  console.log("Original size of: " + element.nodeName + ": " + currentSize);
  element.style.fontSize = ++currentSize + "px"; // Bump up the font size by 1 and concatenate "px" to the result
  console.log("New size of: " + element.nodeName + ": " + getComputedStyle(element).fontSize);
}

// Set a click event on the entire document
document.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  // Run the callback and pass a reference to the actual element that was clicked
  increaseFontSize(event.target);
});
```

```html
<p>A long time ago</p>
<div>In a galaxy far far away</div>
<h1><div>STAR WARS</div></h1>
```

Comment: That interesting but how to see onclick showed in the HTML the font is increasing?
Clicking on the text thefont is not increasing as I see.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a code-sandbox demo. We are getting fontSize from computed styles and then incrementing. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-platform-4zndi

Comment: First, code only answers are not good answers on Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Second, there's no need to post your code at a 3rd party site. Those links can die over time, making your answer meaningless. Just post your code into a code snippet, right here in your answer.