# Capturing the element style - font-size

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, wpbakery

I am using WordPress with WPBakery Web Builder.

I am trying to capture a CSS attribute("font-size") of a specific element in the screen.
In order to capture the element and its attribute I am using JavaScript.

I am running the following script:

```js
var v = document.getElementsByClassName("cb-img-area");
v[0].style.fontSize;
```

and the output is "", even though this is the class's CSS -

```css
.cb-img-area {
    font-size: 72px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-right: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
}
```

How can I get the class's font-size attribute?

Thank you

Comment: Would [that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) help?

Answer (score 0):

Original [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15195209/how-to-get-font-size-in-html)

Just grabbing the style.fontSize of an element may not work. If the font-size is defined by a stylesheet, this will report "" (empty string).

You should use window.getComputedStyle.

```
var el = document.getElementById('foo');
var style = window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
var fontSize = parseFloat(style); 
// now you have a proper float for the font size (yes, it can be a float, not just an integer)
el.style.fontSize = (fontSize + 1) + 'px';
```

Comment: May you can choose, my answer for your question as a solution clicking on the ✔ at the side.