# How to create a button that increases text by 1px in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I need your help. I’m a beginner in JavaScript and I want to create a button that increases text by 1px. Can you help me?

Comment: add some code and html markup that you have, to help us help you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help! `window.getComputedStyle(txt, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');` This is what you can use to get the `fontSize` of an element.

```js
const txt = document.querySelector("#txt");

function changeFontSize(){
  let fontSize = window.getComputedStyle(txt, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
  let newFontSize = Number(fontSize.slice(0,2)) + 1
  txt.style.fontSize = `${newFontSize}px`;
 }
```

```css
#txt {
  font-size: 16px;
 }
```

```html
<div id="txt">Sample Text</div>
<button onclick="changeFontSize()">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that as Som replay above

my way

```
<body>
    <p class="text" style="color:red">Hello Ahmed</p>
    <button class="btn">Click Me</button>

    <script>
         x = 1;
    document.querySelector(".btn").addEventListener("click",function(){
        increseText();
    })

    function increseText(){
        x++; 
        document.querySelector(".text").style.fontSize = x+'px';
        console.log(x)
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>

    <h1 id='h'>My First Heading</h1>
    <p id='p'>My first paragraph.</p>
    <button type='button' id='btn'>increases by 1px</button>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function () {
            var el = document.getElementById('h');
            var style = window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
            var fontSize = parseFloat(style);
            el.style.fontSize = (fontSize + 1) + 'px';
        })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

References :
[How To Get Font Size in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15195209/how-to-get-font-size-in-html)